# Join tables with different sizes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables to join, say A and B. A is smaller with 10k record and B is with a couple of million records. The join is on A.a = B.b. Neither a nor b has an index. I can make changes on the smaller table but not the big one. And I need to convert B.b's data type for the join. 
The query takes long to run. Is there any way I can improve the performance?

Comment: "The query takes long to run. Is there any way I can improve the performance?" add an index.

Comment: Approximately how many rows does the query return? If possible can you post the full query syntax.

Comment: Post more detail or we cannot help. Query syntax, are the tables partitioned, Expected size of the resultset etc.

Comment: An index is unlikely to help if all rows need to be joined.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely join method for best performance is a hash join, so no index would be used.

The column to convert would be the join column from the smaller table, but only because that probably requires fewer CPU cycles.

The query ought to take approximately the same amount of time as a full table scan of the two tables, as long as the hash table built from the smaller table fits in PGA memory -- check v$sql_workarea_active during query execution to monitor the size of the table and whether it spills to temp tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible I would recommend doing the conversion on the smaller table instead and adding an index to the larger table (as the conversion would prevent use of the index anyway).

If you cannot do this for some reason or you want to return a large proportion of the larger table (say more than around 15%) a full table scan may be the most efficient option. More details about this here (http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:9422487749968).

If from the above you conclude that a full table scan is okay (or just necessary) then if you have the hardware for it a parallel hint in the query could help:

```
select /*+ parallel(B,default) */ <columns here> ...
```

In the code above B is the alias of the table you wish to apply the parallel hint to (the big one) and default is the no of cores to use, you can specify a number here instead if you wish.

Without seeing the syntax of the query I cannot advise whether there are any other gains to be had.